# Design TextView to look like a AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a new TextView that looks like a AlertDialog with a style of AlertDialogTheme using this constructor

public TextView (Context context,
AttributeSet attrs,
int defStyleAttr,
int defStyleRes)

I tried already adding R.attr.alertDialogTheme to the parameter defStyleAttr and R.style.AlertDialogTheme to parameter defStyleRes but it didn't work. Am I using the values wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using directly the AlertDialog if you want to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I need to add a clickable link into the AlertDialog's message field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you could try out:

First you could create your own textview and make linkify the part of your textview

```
    val message = TextView(context)
    // R.string.dialog_message =>
    // "Test this dialog following the link to google.com"
    val spannable = SpannableString(R.string.dialog_messag) 
    Linking.addLinks(spannable, 
    Linkify.WEB_URLS)
    message.text = spannable 
    message.movementMethod = 
    LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

    Return Alertdialog
    .Builder(context)
    .setView(message)
    .create()
```

Secondly you could use in your alertDialogs message an html text like this:

```
Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxxxxxxxx'>Click Here</a>")
```

Third you could create a dialogFragment which extends the Dialog class and inflate your own view, here is a reference on how to do that:

https://medium.com/@huseyinozkoc/how-to-use-dialogfragment-in-android-f8095dd0993f

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Aside from your answer, I added some details on the instance of the TextView in order to accommodate the existing dialog alert.